# Number grouped data using VLOOKUP?

Tags: vlookup, ordering

I have a huge dataset with income brackets in column B and BMI values in column C:

```
     totinc       BMI
     15600>18200  19.5
     18200>20800  27.4
     20800>23400  22
     23400>26000  29.5
```

And so on. What formula can i use to order this data by the total income group for example assigning number 1 in column A to those in the 15600>18200 group etc

I have tried using a VLOOKUP formula but it only works when i use one number and no with the >  or < symbols and i do not have time to change the values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Numerical sorting works on numbers. Any function you would like to use for this would at some point have to transform '15600>18200' into numerical data. Since this transformation would be inevitable internally, I recommend you change the representation of total income altogether, as this would make more sense semantically as well.

If it would be too time consuming to do this manually, the process can probably be automised, but the easiest way to go about doing that will depend on how you are storing and manipulating the dataset.

Comment: For example, one way to do this would be to copy and paste into Notepad, do a Find & Replace, and copy and paste back.  Or save as CSV, edit with Notepad, and read back in.